# Is there a function to export Treeview data into a PDF in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have developed a program using Tkinter in Python which allows users to view the list of loaned items(Using the Search function to populate the Treeview)by a Company from the data stored in the Loan Table in MYSQL DB. The  I would like to include a functionality(Print Button) which allows the user to export that displayed data into a PDF. Does Python Tkinter has such functionality? Thanks.[image]

```
class tab_six(Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    

     #Creating a frame, frame2, on the window/canvas for the first tab
    frame6 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="List of loaned items", bd=6) #Frame2 on the window/canvas
    frame6.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=40, pady=20, sticky='NSEW') #Positioning frame2
    self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1) #Configuring the column for the main window/canvas
    self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1) #Configuring the row for the main window/canvas
    
    #Creating LabelFrame in frame2
    upperframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame6, bd=0)
    upperframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
    frame6.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    frame6.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    middleframe= tk.LabelFrame(frame6, bd=5)
    middleframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky = "NSEW")
    frame6.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    frame6. rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    lowerframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame6, bd=0)
    lowerframe.grid(column=0, row=2)
    frame6.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame6. rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
    
    #Labels in frame2
    label31 = tk.Label(upperframe, text="Company Name:", relief='flat')
    label31.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='W')
    label32 = tk.Label(upperframe, text="Asset ID:", relief='flat')
    label32.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='W')
    
    #Combobox Widgets in frame2
    CompanyList = []
    command = "SELECT DISTINCT`Company` from `Loan History` ORDER BY `Company` ASC"
    mycursor.execute(command)
    company_result = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    for n in range(len(company_result)):
        company_result[n] = list(company_result[n])
        CompanyList.append(company_result[n][0])

    searchBox6 = ttk.Combobox(upperframe, width=22, values=CompanyList)
    searchBox6.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, sticky='W', ) #Positioning of the widget
    searchBox6.insert(0, "Please select one")
    searchBox6.configure(state='readonly')
    
    
     #Creating treeview in frame2
    vsb = Scrollbar(middleframe,orient="vertical")
    hsb = Scrollbar(middleframe,orient="horizontal")
    databaseView6 = ttk.Treeview(middleframe, yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    databaseView6.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky = "NSEW")
    middleframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    middleframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    databaseView6["show"] = "headings"
    databaseView6["columns"] = ("asset", "type", "name", "company", "email", "contact", "issue", "date")
    vsb.configure(command=databaseView6.yview)
    hsb.configure(command=databaseView6.xview)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="NS")
    hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="WE")
    
    #Treeview column headings
    databaseView6.heading("asset", text="Asset ID")
    databaseView6.column("asset", anchor= 'center', width=100)
    databaseView6.heading("type", text="Equipment Type")
    databaseView6.column("type", width=250)
    databaseView6.heading("name", text="Loanee")
    databaseView6.column("name", anchor='center', width=150)
    databaseView6.heading("company", text="Company")
    databaseView6.column("company", anchor='center', width=200)
    databaseView6.heading("email", text="Email")
    databaseView6.column("email", anchor='center', width=200)
    databaseView6.heading("contact", text="Contact")
    databaseView6.column("contact", anchor='center', width=100)
    databaseView6.heading("issue", text="Issue")
    databaseView6.column("issue", anchor='center', width=100)
    databaseView6.heading("date", text="Return")
    databaseView6.column("date", anchor='center', width=100)
    
    #Button Widgets in frame2
    btn4 = tk.Button(upperframe, width=7, text="Search", command=lambda:CSearch\
    (searchBox6, databaseView6))
    btn4.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='W')
def CSearch(search_Box, tree):
find = search_Box.get()
    
if (find != "Please select one"):
       
    command = ("SELECT `Asset ID`, `Equipment Type`, `Name`, `Company`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Issue Timestamp`, `Return Timestamp` FROM `Loan History` WHERE `Company`=%s")
    mycursor.execute(command,(search_Box.get(),))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    array2 = []
    
    for n in range(len(myresult)):
        myresult[n] = list(myresult[n])
        array2.append(myresult[n])
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    #Clear the current data in the table
    for x in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(x)
    
    for each in array2:
        tree.insert("", "end", values = [each[0], each[1], each[2], each[3], each[4], each[5], each[6], each[7]], tags=each[0])
                                     
    tree.selection_set(tree.tag_has(find))
   
else:
    valueErrorMessage = "Please select one from the drop down menu"
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", valueErrorMessage)
```

Comment: No, there is no such functionality in tkinter. Only the Canvas widget as a method to export its content (in postscript). You can look into taking a screenshot of your GUI with some other python library though.

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. Would I be able to pass the values using a function and print it in pdf since printing from treeview  is not possible? Like the values in Asset ID, equipment type etc?